# Feed migration for one custom object to other custom object

Tags: custom-object, feeditem, data-migration

I need to migrate Feed data posted on records of custom object. I am able to migrate FeedItem, FeedLikes and FeedComments but not able to find how to migrate FeedLikes on comments postes on FeedItem of custom objects. Any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likes on comments aren't supported in the sObject API. They're only supported in the [Chatter REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_comments.htm) and through the [ConnectApi methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_getLikesForComment) in Apex. If you know the ID of the comment, you can retrieve the likes on that comment.

Comment: I didn't want to hit ConnectApi for migration, thats why asked question. Looks like this is the only solution as of now, if number of comments are in thousands, lot of API hit will be required to migrate all likes information

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it's the only solution as of now.